# Error: could not find function “rxGetOption” in Revolution R Open

Tags: r, revolution-r, rro, microsoft-r

I downloaded and installed Revolution R Open. Current Version of R is 3.1.1 (2014-07-10) -- "Sock it to Me" and version of Revolution R Open is 8.0 beta. I have started basic tutorial from converting data to .xdf format(internal to Revolution).

```
myTrainCsv <- file.path(rxGetOption("data"), "train.csv")
```

However I receive a following error:

> Error in file.path(rxGetOption("data"), : could not find function
>   "rxGetOption"

It seems to me a newbie error. Anyway I can not find an answer just googling it. Please, help me to resolve the issue with the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Revolution R Open](http://www.revolutionanalytics.com/revolution-r-open) is an open source distribution of R, adding the fast MKL math libraries.

The function `rxGetOption()` and the XDF big data functionality is part of `RevoScaleR` and only available in [Revolution R Enterprise](http://www.revolutionanalytics.com/revolution-r-enterprise) (RRE).

If you are a student or at an academic institution, then you might qualify for the free [academic license](http://www.revolutionanalytics.com/academic-and-public-service-programs).  The academic license allows you full access to all the features in RRE, including the XDF big data features in `RevoScaleR`.