# Node errors in Revolution R Open with the Forecast package

Tags: r, parallel-processing, forecasting, rro

This seems like more of a StackOverflow question than a CrossValidated question so let's see if I'm right...

I'm tinkering around with Revolution R Open (RRO) since I'd like to take advantage of the faster MKL math libraries.

I took some code that works just fine in regular R, tried it in RRO, and got the following error when I attempted to use the `tbats()` function from the `forecast` package.

```
> ts(data, seasonal.periods=c(7,365.25))
> fit<-tbats(myts)
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  3 nodes produced errors; first error: could not find function "fitSpecificBATS"
```

If I need to provide some reproducible code/data, I can. However, it appears to me to be more of an issue with the parallelization of the `tbats` function itself since using the `ets` function within the same package works just fine.

After a quick search, [Error: could not find function “rxGetOption” in Revolution R Open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27076361/error-could-not-find-function-rxgetoption-in-revolution-r-open/27076605#27076605) looked promising but seems to be more about RRE vs RRO functions.

Any clue as to what is going on and what I might be able to do for a solution?